# Issue with sculpt mode in Blender 2.8

Tags: sculpting

I'm currently trying to sculpt a plane. Looks simple, but in my case, I obtain this:

[image: what a strange thing]

or:

[image: what a strange way to sculpt]

Details:

- The "weird thing" happens only after the first click with the brush. The first click works well, as intended (like in the second image).
- I'm on Ubuntu 19.04, maybe it's due to a bug.
- I'm using the multiresolution modifier, no dyntopo, but even with the subdivision surface modifier it happens.
- I restarted my computer, nothing have changed.
- When I was sculpting, I was in Top ortho view.
- Maybe, I've forgotten something.